# For Loops in Callbacks

Tags: java, callback

I am learning how to code in Java and I came across 'Using Interfaces for Callbacks' in the book that I'm using. There is a class called Data which computes the average of the measures of any given objects with a method called

```
public static double max(Object[] objects, Measurer m)
{
    double largest = 0;
    for (Object obj : objects)
    {
        if(m.measure(obj) > largest)
        {
            largest = m.measure(obj);
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

This code works perfectly fine and I do understand it, however, I tried using a normal for loop with `for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)` and I kept getting an error that states

> "java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.awt.Rectangle; cannot be cast to java.awt.Rectangle".

This is the code that I'm trying to use.

```
public static double max(Object[] objects, Measurer m)
{
    double largest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {   
        double obj = m.measure(objects);
        if(m.measure(obj) > largest)
        {
            largest = m.measure(obj);
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

My question is what does this exception really mean, and is there a way to do it the way I wanted to with the normal for loop? I'd like to use the normal for loop just because it's a bit easier to read for me personally than the enhanced loop; even though I know the enhanced loop more compact.

Extra Info: This class is called Data and it uses the Measurer type which is an interface with a single method `double measure(Object anObject)` to measure objects of the type Object. The Measurer interface is implemented by a class called AreaMeasurer which computes and returns the area of a rectangle object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
double obj = m.measure(objects);
```

you are trying to assign to the obj variable the result of mesaure method by passing table of Objects to it, instead a single Object. I suppose you wanted to do something like that:

```
double obj = m.measure(objects[i]);
```

This is the code witch is doing exactly the same as this with for each loop:

```
public static double max(Object[] objects, Measurer m)
{
    double largest = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<objects.length; i++)
    {
        if(m.measure(objects[i]) > largest)
        {
            largest = m.measure(objects[i]);
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

I think you don't really understand the way for each loop works. In your example obj variable is initialized with next value from objects table every single time. You can identify this variable as objects[i] where the i is number of loop execution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `Object obj = objects[i];` are passing an array of objects to measure method (`double obj = m.measure(objects);`)  and this line needs to be removed.

```
public static double max(Object[] objects, Measurer m)
{
    double largest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {   
        Object obj = objects[i];

        if(m.measure(obj) > largest)
        {
            largest = m.measure(obj);
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the `objects.get(i)` that is needed for getting the correct object on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because you are passing wrong object type to the `measure` method.
It expects `Object` but you are passing `Object[]` instance.

In the normal for loop `i` is the index of the object in the array.
You need to get the current object from the array before you measure it like this:

```
Object obj = objects[i];
```

Then you can measure and compare.

Answer (score 0):

This exception actually means that somewhere inside the method `measure` of the class `AreaMeasurer`, the `Object` parameter you are passing is being cast to `java.awt.Rectangle`.

Since you are passing the entire array to the method, that probably means that you are passing a `java.awt.Rectangle[]` (in the exception it's reported as `[Ljava.awt.Rectangle;`).

To fix it, you should follow the advice given in the other answers:

```
Object obj = objects[i];
```